# Very basic task using foldr

Tags: haskell, fold

I just used a very simple example used in some lecture notes with my ghci:

```
 foldr (:) [] 1 2
```

expecting the result

```
   [1,2]
```

However, I get an error. I get an error everytime when I try to use ++ or : as the function given to foldr.

Apparently I am making some pretty obvious mistake but I still cannot seem to find it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: whats the error message? you can you `:t` to check the type of `foldr`

Comment: this should be like `foldr (:) [] [1,2]`

Comment: It is generally best to include error messages and not just mentioning "an error". This helps people a great deal to help you :) Even though you accepted an answer including the error message could help people with similar problems find this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You used `foldr` like a variadic function by passing it two arguments `1` and `2` instead of `[1, 2]`.

When you run into trouble like that, just check the function's type. You can do that in GHCi:

```
Prelude> :t foldr
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

So you see that the first argument should be a function `(a -> b -> b)`. You used `(:)` for that, which is o.k. You can check the type of the partially applied function as well:

```
Prelude> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Substituting `b` with `[a]` gives us:

```
Prelude> :t foldr (:)
foldr (:) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Next, you gave `[]` as a base case.

```
Prelude> :t foldr (:) []
foldr (:) [] :: [a] -> [a]
```

So the resulting function is of type `[a] -> [a]`. What should you make of this? You have to pass it a list to get a list back! Passing the argument list `[1, 2]`:

```
Prelude> :t foldr (:) [] [1,2]
foldr (:) [] [1,2] :: Num a => [a]
```

Is accepted by the type checker and yields the result:

```
Prelude> foldr (:) [] [1,2]
[1,2]
```

I hope this helps type-debugging your programs...