# How can i count elements of a tuple in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

So i've got a list of tuples like this one :

```
xs = [("a","b"),("a","c"),("b","d")
```

and i want a function that counts the number of times a certain value appears in the first position of the tuple. If i used the list xs and the letter 'a', it would return the value 2, because the letter 'a' appears two times in the first position of the tuple. This function shouldn't be recursive.

So what i've got is this:

```
f xs = (fst $ unzip xs) / length(xs)
```

Now i have all the elements down on a list. this would be easy if it was recursive, but if i don't want it that way, how can i do it ?

Comment: No, is a list of multiple exercises that i want to do, in order to study for my final exam, but i'm struggling with this part of the book. But thanks anyway

Comment: @dcarou On stackoverflow, we have problems with people copy pasting answers for homework credit. This is cheating and frankly annoys pretty much all the users here, so when you post questions like these people want to see that you're trying too

Comment: @aga i've tried to make function that returns all the first elements of the tuples, but i want to add 1 for every time they appear, and that's what i'm having a hard time.

Answer (score 4):

If we're not using recursion, we need to use some higher order functions. In particular, `filter` looks helpful, it removes elements who don't satisfy some condition.

Well if we use `filter` we can get a list of all elements with the first element being the correct thing.

```
 count :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> Int
 count x = length . filter ((== x) . fst)
```

I suppose since you're studying, you should work to understand some folds, start with

```
count x = foldr step 0
  where step (a, b) r | a == x = 1 + r
                      | otherwise = r
```

Comment: in order to get the all first elements can i do this instead ? f xs = (fst $ unzip xs)

Comment: @dcarou That's not well typed, you're dividing a list by a number.

Comment: The `fst $ unzip xs` is fine though. Then just use `length . filter (x ==)`

Comment: Can you explain what the recursive function does ? Cause i'm not understanding it very well

Comment: sorry, i'm really struggling to learn the language. so basically, what does the "foldr step 0" mean exactly ?

Comment: @dcarou Try reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463019/very-basic-task-using-foldr/18463437#18463437 it may help

Answer (score 2):

If you map the first elements into a list find all occurences of your value and count the length of the resulting list:

```
countOccurences :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Int
countOccurences e = length . filter ((==)e) . map fst
```